# Does the separation between two charges change or remain constant when another charged particle is placed at a point where net electric field is zero?

Tags: forces, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

When we place a charge $C$  between two  charged particles $A$ and $B$, at a point the force experienced by that charge $C$ is zero. Is the converse also true, that the other two charges also don't change their position and remain at rest? Or does the distance between $A$ and $B$ change due to the placement of $C$? If it does,then will the charge $C$ experience any net force due to change in seperation?

Comment: What is the nature of charges of $A$,$B$ and $C$? Do they have the same charge and mass? And what do you think will happen? Please mention these details in the question.

Comment: A and B postive while C being negative

Comment: There is no system of more than one positive point charge that is in equilibrium, so the system can’t “remain at rest”